getServerSession is not working for Next Auth in Next.js app
I can't create a session in my app/api/auth/login/route.ts file. I only get, 'Session creation failed' response. I tried to solve it but no luck. I added the codes that are needed for clarification. I added all my files that are needed here.
My app/api/auth/login/route.ts,
```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import UserMapper from '@/lib/mappers/UserMapper';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
//import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route';

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = await req.json();

    // Fetch the user from the database
    const user = await UserMapper.getUserByEmail(email);

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Invalid Email' }, { status: 401 });
    }

    // Compare the provided password with the hashed password in the database
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Invalid Password' }, { status: 401 });
    }

    console.log("Testing authOptions", authOptions);

    // Create a session for the user
    //const session = await getServerSession({ req, authOptions });
    //const session = await getServerSession({ req, res: NextResponse }, authOptions);
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    
    //console.log(session);

    // Check if the session was created successfully
    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Session creation failed' }, { status: 500 });
    }

    // Return a success response with the user data
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: 'Logged in successfully',
      user: session.user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'An error occurred during login' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Here is the options for my [nextauth]/route.ts file,
```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import UserMapper from '@/lib/mappers/UserMapper';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        const user = await UserMapper.getUserByEmail(email);

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('Invalid Email');
        }

        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!isPasswordValid) {
          throw new Error('Invalid Password');
        }

        return { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      console.log('JWT callback:', { token, user });
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log('Session callback:', { session, token });
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin', // Custom sign-in page
  },
  debug: true,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Here is the file for middleware.ts,
``
// app/middleware.ts
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/api/products/:path*', // Protects all paths under /api/products
    '/products/admin/:path*', // Protects all paths under /products/admin
  ],
};
```

File for .env,
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@localhost:3308/shopping_cart" NEXTAUTH_SECRET="your-random-secret-key"
File for package.json,
     "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.15.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "formidable": "^3.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "prisma": "^5.15.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  } 

